# Is it safe to remove npm-cache folder in windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, caching, npm

`npm cache clean -f` is not able to clear the `npm_cache` folder located at the path `C:\Users\jerry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`. Though it clears some of the files in this folder.

Output of command: `npm WARN    I sure hope you know what you are doing.`

However, [Node.js](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) page says clean command will delete all data out of the cache folder.

So, why is it not happening? Would it be okay if I manually delete the folder?

I'm on Windows 10 with node 8.7.0

Comment: I guess these are from global node_modules.

Comment: @DanielRuf No, the global npm modules are in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: The cache is used for local and global modules.

Answer (score 18):

Yes it is safe,
I have deleted npm and npm-cache folder manually and reinstall node its working fine.

Comment: Is it necessary to reinstall node after manually deleting npm and npm cache folder content? I haven't reinstalled node and so far, everything seems to work good. So, just want to make sure if it's necessary to reinstall node in order to avoid problems in future.

Comment: No it's not necessary to reinstall node.

Answer (score 9):

for Window 7 8 10 user

Run this:

```
md C:\npm-cache
```

And then:

```
npm config set cache C:\npm-cache
```

Its Working For me